# android OnGlobalLayoutListener how to retrieve data

Tags: android, listeners

I am using OnGlobalLayoutListener. How can I use data from this listener? Especially I need lAngle.

```
        past_edittext.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    int height = past_edittext.getHeight();
                    int width = past_edittext.getWidth();
                    int top = past_edittext.getTop();
                    int left = past_edittext.getLeft();

                    // center coordinates of EditText
                    past_edittextX = left + width / 2;
                    past_edittextY = top + height / 2;
                    lAngle = (float) (Math
                            .atan((totalCenterY - past_edittextY)
                                    / (totalCenterX - past_edittextX)) * 180 / Math.PI);
                }
            });
```

Comment: depend on where you went to access `lAngle` variable if you want to access value of `lAngle` in same class then make it class level field and if you want to use value of `lAngle` in other classes then use `SharedPreferences` to store it

Comment: I want to use it in the same class but in another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your class declare the following

```
private float lAngle;
```

then you can access lAngle after you've set it from the globallayoutlistener

```
...
past_edittext.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int height = past_edittext.getHeight();
                int width = past_edittext.getWidth();
                int top = past_edittext.getTop();
                int left = past_edittext.getLeft();

                // center coordinates of EditText
                past_edittextX = left + width / 2;
                past_edittextY = top + height / 2;
                lAngle = (float) (Math
                        .atan((totalCenterY - past_edittextY)
                                / (totalCenterX - past_edittextX)) * 180 / Math.PI);
            }
        });
}

public void someOtherMethod(){
    if (lAngle != null)
        // do something...
```